# Strong references within weak references

Tags: java, memory, weak-references

in Java, are strong references accessible from weakly reachable objects are considered as strong references?

Example :

- I can access X by a weak reference.
- I can access Y by a weak reference.
- I can access X by a pointer from Y.
- I can access Y by a pointer from X.

If there is no other pointer on X and Y, I would expect them to get garbage-collected. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both objects may be garbage-collected; a strong reference from a weakly-referenced object counts as a weak reference.

Answer (score 6):

Even though the term *strong reference* is used, perhaps it is better to think in terms of *reach-ability*.

That is, if the object is *strongly reachable* from a root object it is not eligibility for reclamation -- otherwise, it is. A *strong reference* to an object only referenced through a *weak reference* is not *strongly reachable*. However, the strong reference is *still* a strong reference.

Happy coding.